# How to use select parameters in html tags in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, datasource

```
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlKitapDataSoruce" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DatabaseProjeConnectionString %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Kitap] ORDER BY [satisSayisi] DESC" >

            </asp:SqlDataSource>
            <% for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) %>
                <% { %>

                    <div class="indexKitap">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="<% %>" runat="server" ImageUrl="<%  %>" />
                        <asp:Label ID="LblKitapAd" runat="server" Text="<% %>"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
```

I have this code and I want to use the columns called `foto_path` as ImageUrl and `kitap_ad` as Text of Label, but I don't know how I can use parameters of datasource in html tags.  I tried to use like `<%#foto_path%>` but it gives error.  How can I use a parameter of a datasource in a html tag?

Comment: What would you do in you do not know the value of `i` (number of records in our datasource)? And how would the content of the for loop be aware that it is associated with the SqlKitapDataSoruce datasource? Charlie's answer is one way of doing what you want. http://www.asp.net is one of the starting points you can take a look at to learn more or to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a data-bound control, like [Repeater](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater(v=vs.85).aspx). Something like:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlKitapDataSoruce">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="indexKitap">
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("foto_path")  %>' />
            <asp:Label ID="LblKitapAd" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("kitap_ad") %>'></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: remember to put the content between an item template: `<ItemTemplate>...</ItemTemplate>` inside the repeater control